# debugging celery + django stack

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I have a Celery task in a Django module that manipulates the backend database. The tasks are started like this:

```
for r in results:
    try:
        r.wait()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc(e))
```

When I run the code, this is what happens in the terminal:

```
2012-03-26 18:19:49,153:ERROR:g: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./xyz.py", line 42, in g
    r.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-2.4.6-py2.7.egg/celery/result.py", line 99, in wait
    return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-2.4.6-py2.7.egg/celery/result.py", line 95, in get
    interval=interval)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-2.4.6-py2.7.egg/celery/backends/amqp.py", line 147, in wait_for
    raise self.exception_to_python(meta["result"])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is this IndexError coming from my code or somewhere from Celery? If it's from my code, how do I trace it? Logging messages before and after call to wait() do not show anything strange.

Comment: Looks like it's coming from the AMQP backend within Celery. Might be worth looking at the code on GitHub: https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/master/celery/backends/amqp.py